# Is there a way to configure AWS SES or Cognito to use my own SMTP server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses

I am building an app that requires user sign in and I am using AWS Cognito. I am running out of test emails. So I wanted to use a service like Mailtrap for test users. I have not been able to find this setting in Cognito OR SES.

Comment: Many strategies for dealing with this situation. Each test, just delete the Cognito user, you can then register a new user and send an email to that address, or verify a domain and you can then move out of the sandbox and send mails to any address.

Comment: SES is SMTP server, so we cannot use it with another server. Cognito doesn't relate to STMP at all.